# Array of arrays in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make and array that contains arrays, some are of double's, some are of int's.

This does not work:

```
var arrayZero = [1,2,3]
var arrayOne = [4.0,5.0,6.0]

var arrayofArrayZeroandOne: [[AnyObject]] = arrayZero.append(arrayOne)
```

How can I append arrays to an array so that I can get 5.0 if I write arrayofArrayZeroandOne[1][1] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would take advantage of Swift's type safety. Going the Any route could introduce bugs if you're not careful adding and retrieving from the array.

```
var numbers = Array<Array<NSNumber>>()  // A bit clearer IMO
var numbers = [[NSNumber]]()            // Another way to declare
numbers.append(arrayZero)
numbers.append(arrayOne)
```

Then when you do something like

```
let five = numbers[1][1] // will be 5.0
```

You know it will be of type NSNumber. Further Swift won't let you put anything else into the array unless it's an NSNumber

**Without appends solution**

```
var numbers = Array<Array<NSNumber>>() [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0]
]
```

Comment: Great, this is the answer closest to what I was asking for - Thanks to all of you !

Comment: In your example, if I try to add numbers[10] = [8,9,10] for example.  I get an error.  I guess it is because it has not been initialised to be that size yet, so there is no space yet for index=10.  But how could I do that, initialise the array to hold say tableViewRows.count.. arrays?

Comment: Well you'll have to execute a loop over the number of rows in your tableView and append more arrays of NSNumbers

Comment: Ahh, yes, sorry - shortcut here, figured it out :-)  for i in 0...10{
    numbers.append([NSNumber]())
}

Comment: actually this is a bit cleaner I guess: var numbers = Array(count: tableViewRows.count, repeatedValue:[NSNumber]())

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `[[Any]]` (and note that `append` mutates in place):

```
let arrayZero = [1, 2, 3]
let arrayOne = [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]

let arrayofArrayZeroAndOne: [[Any]] = [arrayZero, arrayOne]

let a = arrayofArrayZeroAndOne[0][0] // of type Any
```

Comment: I get an error when I do that in playground "Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code=1, address=0x1).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an append, you can construct the array directly:

```
var arrayZero = [1, 2, 3]
var arrayOne = [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
var arrayofArrayZeroandOne: [[AnyObject]] = [arrayZero, arrayOne]

println(arrayofArrayZeroandOne[1][1]) // Prints 5
```